# rolling multiple dice and taking the max value observed and plotting a histogram

Tags: python, random, probability, dice

Considering an event where you roll multiple dice and take the max value observed. I am writing a function that will randomly simulate this event multiple times and return the maximum value obtained in each trial.

Not really sure what I have done is correct. Also, I would like to plot a histogram of resulting max values but plt.hist dosen't seem right.
Any insights will be appreciated

```
import random
def multipleRolls(numberoftrials, numberofdice):
   trial_list=[]
   min = 1
   max = 6
   for i in range (1,numberoftrials+1):
       m=0
       for j in range(1,numberofdice+1):
           k = random.randint(min, max)
           if m<k:
               m=k
       trial_list.append(m)
   plt.hist(trial_list)
   plt.show()
   print(trial_list)
multipleRolls(3,5)
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Why don't you think the histogram is right? The more dice you have, the more likely it will be that the maximum is always 6.

Comment: yeah.. something just did not feel right so I though of asking the community to see if I was on the right track

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a proof to see the correct number of die are being rolled and the maximum is selected you could create a list of all rolled die and print the answer, then pass the result to a normal plt.hist, example:

```
import random
def multipleRolls(numberoftrials, numberofdice):
   trial_list=[]
   alltrials=[]
   min = 1
   max = 6
   for i in range (1,numberoftrials+1):
       singletrial=[]
       m=0
       for j in range(1,numberofdice+1):
           k = random.randint(min, max)
           if m<k:
               m=k
           singletrial.append(k)    
       alltrials.append(singletrial)
       trial_list.append(m)
       
   return trial_list, alltrials

trial_list, alltrials = multipleRolls(3,5)
print(trial_list, alltrials)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.hist(trial_list)
plt.show()
```

Example response:

```
[5, 6, 6] [[1, 1, 5, 1, 5], [5, 2, 6, 2, 4], [5, 2, 6, 4, 6]]
```

[image]